# Critical random slowdown issue using KVM/QEMU

Tags: 14.04, performance, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm having a critical issue with KVM/QEMU which is severely impacting one of my projects and I don't know where to put my hands.

I've set up a brand new physical server configured with a 2 x Intel Xeon E5504 (4c/4t) and 16GB of RAM. I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 (linux-image 3.13.0-44-generic) along with KVM 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.10, QEMU 1.22, libvirt 1.2.2.

I need to set up several VM instances that have to be fired up on demand when I need to analyze big data, with a timeout of 2 minutes (they should end way before that though), after that I kill the analysis. I decided to set up 8 VMs (one per thread) with 1GB of ram assigned each one, and all of them run Windows XP. All the VMs use the qcow2 format.

I installed the first VM and took a snapshot of it (virsh snapshot-create-as), then I replicated the same snapshot on all the other instances.

The first time I run all the VMs everything run smoothly, the VMs fire up and shut down perfectly.

However, after a while I turn them on and off, all the VMs start being slow as hell, like if KVM is not doing anymore hardware emulation and QEMU falls back in software emulation. The consequence is that all the analysis hit the critical timeout and got killed

Even when all the VMs run at the same time the two CPUs are not 100% loaded and the RAM itself is only 56% busy, the swap file is totaly free.

I tried tuning up the I/O scheduler deadline by changing the parameters:

read_expire at 80
write_expire at 1500
fifo batch at 16 
front merges at 1
write starved at 6

and I set up the VMs with io=native disk configuration.

This last round of tuning improved the situation, yet it doesn't fix it as I've just raised the amount of time the VMs can run without any issue before reaching the fatal slowdown (which now arrives after several hours).

Could somebody of you guys give me a help in trying to figure out why this behavior is happening?  I don't know anymore where to put my hands on.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It is almost impossible to give you advice as there are too many variables. First, is virtualization enabled in your BIOS ? Did you clone the hard drives ? and you are messing with various i/o settings. Could be a problem with XP or some process you are running on XP. Last your version of kvm is somewhat outdated, so, if you file a bug report upstream they are going to tell you to update to the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I know it's quite difficult to give advice as it's quite complicated situation, I'll try to shed some light by answering your questions. 1) Yes, the virtualization is active on the BIOS 2) I created the first VM and took a snapshot using virsh (virsh snapshot-create-as), then a simply copied the qcow2 image (containing both the disk and the snapshot data) and replicated it for the other VMs, associating every qcow2 image copy to a VM. 3) KVM is the last updated build for Ubuntu Server 14.04,at least from Ubuntu repositories.Many thanks for your support!much appreciated

Comment: Well you sort of need to start with one machine and one set of settings at a time. FWIW, IMHO support for KVM lags on Debian and Ubuntu and it is for this reason I use Fedroa or Proxmox for virtualization

Comment: Qemu should be 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.10. The operational difference between 1.X and 2 is very significant.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks for your help! I was actually thinking about moving to another distro like Fedora or Centos, as they might be better supported by KVM

Comment: @DougSmythies I installed the package qemu-kvm which should include both QEMU and KVM, it's the last updated build available on Ubuntu Trusty

Comment: To give you guys another detail, I ran a I/O test through fio and this is the result: **read** : _io=3071.7MB, bw=958802B/s, iops=234, runt=3359271msec_
**write**: _io=1024.4MB, bw=319739B/s, iops=78, runt=3359271msec_